# Develop application with libspotify

Tags: api, key, spotify, libspotify

Now I want to develop an application on ARM with libspotify to play music.So I buy a premium account on spotify to get the API key.My original idea is that anyone who has my equipment could enjoy the music served by spotify,but the spotify does not allow to play the same song by the same account on different equipment at the same time.And even the user has their own account,they can not login from the application developed by my API key.How can I resolve the contradiction

Comment: Why exactly cannot the user login with their own account?

Comment: The API key does not prevent your application being used by other accounts. It just gives Spotify a way to track app usage and possibly block mis-programmed "runaway" apps. (It's probably less useful against outright malicious apps, since it's impossible to fully secure API keys.) See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884916/preventing-misuse-of-libspotify-key

Comment: When I use another free account to login by the demo that spotify provide,I failed.Do I have to need another premium account?Does any other people who want to use my application have to pay for the premium account?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Terms-of-Service of Spotify. Only programming-related questions about the spotify API are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As per Spotify's Docs, users must have premium accounts to use that functionality.

Login

To access Spotify functionality the user will need log in using Spotify or Facebook credentials. The logged in account needs to be a PREMIUM one. Note that in the Spotify login flow can be shown when the user e.g. tries to play music, it doesn’t need to come when launching the app. When logging in the user will need to accept our terms of service: spotify.com/legal.